# Ajax not working - keep getting $.ajax is not a function error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

No matter what I do I keep getting the same error "`$.ajax` is not a function" and I can't seem to figure it out.

I have been working on this for a while and this is what I have tried.

**My Debugging / Troubleshooting Steps** -
*(I am laying this out so it will be a resource to help easily resolve more common problems.)*

**1. jQuery is installed.**

Ran the following test:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($.ajax);
  alert('pre test success');
  if(window.jQuery) { 
    alert('post test success');
  } else {
    alert('test fail Jquery did not load!');
  }
});
```

**2. Tested current and previous versions of jQuery  (I am NOT using slim release).**

*(Note: it appears the slim version does not include Ajax)*

I have even tried to include Ajax library completely seperate along with jQuery library using jQuery Builder at http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/

**3. Tested many different syntax to help eliminate syntax error.**

For example from answer to similar question on stack overflow:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: myData,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: callback
});
```

Even this one directly from the jquery home page:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/api/getWeather",
  data: {
    zipcode: 97201
  },
  success: function( result ) {
   $( "#weather-temp" ).html( "<strong>" + result + "</strong> degrees");
  }
});
```

I have also tried to change `$.ajax` to `jQuery.ajax` etc with no luck.

**4. Confirm I am using document ready**

See code for #1  `alert('pre test success');`

**5. Confirm jQuery library is included before script with Ajax.**

Check

---

It seems no matter what I do nothing solves this problem. And for the what it' worth I am running this on XAMP and DigitalOcean server and getting the same results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you link the actual page that is having the problems?

Comment: I know this has been asked a dozen times on here, but all the others seem to be rather simple isolated events with most being pretty simple and repetitive. Hopefully, this will provide a more "all-inclusive" resource.

Comment: We need more information in order to resolve this.

Comment: What does the command `console.log($().jquery)` say, when you execute it in your console window?

Comment: @cars10  this is what I get:


`3.1.1 -ajax,-ajax/jsonp,-ajax/load,-ajax/parseXML,-ajax/script,-ajax/var/location,-ajax/var/nonce,-ajax/var/rquery,-ajax/xhr,-manipulation/_evalUrl,-event/ajax,-effects,-effects/animatedSelector,-effects/Tween,-deprecated`

Comment: Ahh, what a tricky situation: bootstrap itself including slim-jquery ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe are you using other libraries which could mess up with the use of the $ sign ?

Have a look there : [Avoiding Conflicts with Other Libraries (jQuery)](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

Comment: @Piki  This actually helped I was testing out the No-Conflict mode and begin actually looking at all of the js scripts that I am running that could potentially be causing conflicts I discovered that the Bootstrap template had a link to the jquery slim buried in some other script links.

Comment: In this case, it was another version of jQuery that was causing the conflict!

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that your jquery plugin is loaded before the ajax code is called by the browser...
Also ensure to download the latest jquery plugin and test other jquery functionality to be sure if Jquery is working fine in the code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "demoTest.txt", success: function(result){
            $("#div").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
<div id="div"><h2>Let AJAX Change this Text with another another</h2></div>
```

Comment: if the problem still occur after calling the jQuery library directly from the source, try calling another version...possibly there is an update to the plugin that has one conflict or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem thanks to @Piki

As I was going through my js libraries looking for potential conflicts, I discovered a link to "jQuery Slim" buried in some other script links at the bottom of the Bootstrap template I am using which was overriding my other jQuery files.

**MY SOLUTION WAS....**

**Removing a link to jQuery Slim release at the bottom of my page which I was unaware existed.**

It was another version of jQuery causing the conflict.